# Using an oracle sequence directly in the CONNECT BY clause

Tags: oracle, sequence, connect-by

I have below query to use the sequence from CONNECT BY clause and insert into the table

```
INSERT INTO DF_SUBJECTS (SUBJECT_ID)    
SELECT 'CUST' || LPAD(your_sequence.NEXTVAL, 3, '0'), ROWNUM
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT your_sequence.CURRVAL FROM dual);
```

Error return ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

Below is the definition of sequence:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE your_sequence INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 001 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 NOCYCLE CACHE 20 NOORDER ;
```

If calling sequence is not allowed in connect by clause, any suggestion to populate the value using sequence in select query?

Comment: Why would you do this? If the sequence is at 5, you would generate 5 rows numbered 6,7,8,9 and 10. I fail to see the purpose. Perhaps you are generating bogus test data? You'd get the same thing by querying the table your insert these values into or just hard coding the # of rows you want. If you want to double the # of rows with bogus data, simply `insert  select` from and back into the table so you get one new row for every existing row. There's almost never a need to consult .CurrVal

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  If you are ultimately trying to insert rows into a table somewhere, you'd use the sequence in the `insert` statement.  You're not going to be able to use the sequence in a `select` statement because it wouldn't work the way you expect.  SQL is declarative-- you don't control how the database chooses to execute the query so the sequence might get incremented many times for each row.

Comment: @PaulW, i have table to insert with the running number populated using sequence. Updated in the question

Comment: If the goal is to populate a table, you'd do that in the `insert` statement not in the `select`.

Comment: @Justin Cave, i'm inserting new records to the table using insert into...select There are more values passed from, only the subject_id that required the population logic

Comment: How many rows are you trying to insert, and why would that be correlated with the sequence?

Comment: Is it mandatory to do it using query, why not create a procedure or even a simple PL/SQL block, then you can use a loop and insert any number of data, you won't need to use the CONNECT BY clause?

Comment: just to add have to tried the make the connect by select query as inner query and then use that for INSERT, maybe that might work. meaning INSERT INTO DF_SUBJECTS (SUBJECT_ID)    
SELECT  * FROM (SELECT 'CUST' || LPAD(your_sequence.NEXTVAL, 3, '0'), ROWNUM
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT your_sequence.CURRVAL FROM dual));